# CURL Error on accessing HTTPS site via a HTTP proxy

Tags: curl, https, proxy, openssl

I am facing an issue with CURL that when I am trying to access an Internet site for which we have opened a firewall from our datacenter via a HTTP proxy.
The issue below is as follows as seen in curl verbose mode (I have change the actual IP & site information for security purpose):-

```
curl -v -x http://10.X.X.X:8080 https://jfm.XXXX.de/rest/api/2/issue/ABCD-100
* About to connect() to proxy 10.X.X.X port 8080
*   Trying 10.X.X.X... connected
* Connected to 10.X.X.X (10.X.X.X) port 8080
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to jfm.XXXX.de:443
> CONNECT jfm.XXXX.de:443 HTTP/1.0
> Host: jfm.XXXX.de:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    CApath: none
* SSLv2, Client hello (1):
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to jfm.XXXX.de:8080
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to jfm.XXXX.de:8080
```

so the issue is that the port for the internet site is 443 but above you can see it is converting to 8080, hence please help me to resolve the connectivity issue.

Comment: curl 7.15.5 is more than **12** years old. I think an upgrade might be a good idea...

Comment: Thank you, but as we cannot update the curl part, got a workaround working, strangely but it works. the command is curl -H "Authorization:Basic XXXXX" -X GET http://jfm.XXXX.de:443/rest/api/2/issue/ABCD-100 --proxy 10.X.X.X:8080